# Python - loop through files in different folders

Tags: python, loops, directory, nested

I want to extract data from multiple files nested within subfolders.

e.g. folder structure

```
A/B/C/D.dat
A/B/E/F.dat
A/B/G/H.dat
```

The code I came up with is:

```
import os
values = 2
doc = []
rootdir = 'C:/A/B'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.dat'):
            with open (file, 'rt') as myfile:
                    current_line = 0
                    for mylines in myfile:
                            if current_line == values:
                                doc.append()
                                break
                            current_line += 1
            continue

print(doc)
```

Error I struggle to solve:

```
...with open (file, 'rt') as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D.dat'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you are looking for the third line of all the .dat files in the subdirectories.  There are using pathlib.Path you can do quite a lot of this in a few simple steps.

```
from pathlib import Path
doc = []
line_number_of_each_file = values = 2

for file in Path('C:/A/B').rglob('*.dat'):
    doc.append(file.readtext().splitlines()[line_number_of_each_file])

print(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Though your solution is not the cleanest. The bug you are getting comes from

```py
            with open (file, 'rt') as myfile:
```

which should be replaced with

```
            with open (subdir + "/" + file, 'rt') as myfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is due to missing of complete file path. So you need make sure that "A/B/C/D.dat" should be there in file which you are trying to open as myfile.

you can add the below snippet to your logic to achieve it.

`for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath=subdir+'/'+file`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My file structure is something like this:

```
project
|__dir1
|  |__file_to_read.txt
|
|__dir2
   |__file_reader.py
```

In order to actually find the other file, I have to go out one directory, to the parent dir of my `.py` file. I used this code originally:

```py
import os

current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

file_to_read = os.path.relpath('project/dir1/file_to_read', current_path)
```

This worked for me, but I later changed over to a different version. The reason is not for any reason you'll have to worry about, other than evidently this next module is better for path crawling than `os`.

```py
from pathlib import Path

parent = Path.cwd().parent
file_to_read = Path(f'{parent}/project/dir1/file_to_read.txt').resolve()
```

Maybe this would be more preferable, as it's more highly recommended to me. I hope this helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to call filename.dat. Instead you should access A/B/C/filename.dat .
Join the pathname + filename for this:

```
import os
values = 2
doc = []
rootdir = 'A/B/C/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            print(file)
            file = os.path.join(rootdir,subdir,file)
            with open (file, 'rt') as myfile:
                    current_line = 0
                    for mylines in myfile:
                            if current_line == values:
                                doc.append(mylines)
                                break
                            current_line += 1
            continue

print(doc)
```